# Angular project acting different on Windows 10 vs macOS

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular-ngmodel

I have one that has stumped us. We have an existing Angular project that a co-worker has pulled down onto their Windows machine. At this point node, npm and angular are all at the same version. The project itself is identical on both machines. Works flawless on macOS but having issues on Windows 10.

Two components are being flagged in VSCode with the error:

`X component is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator`

However, every component is created with Angular CLI, and like I mentioned before everything is fine on macOS so at this point I can only imagine it's *somewhere* in the config files. I just have no clue where.

Here's the whole HeaderComponent as an example (this is one where VSCode is highlighting the entire component in red from line 6 down. It's also highlighting it as an error in the @NgModule declarations array within the app module:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuService } from 'src/app/services/menu.service';
import { MenuComponent} from '../menu/menu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MenuComponent,
  ]
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public menu: MenuService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This looks fine to me, and works as expected on my machine, but it isn't compiling correctly on the Windows machine.

Any thoughts? Maybe something else we need to check that's possibly not up to date on the Windows machine other than node, npm and Angular CLI?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to declare HeaderComponent as both a component and a module. Why is the NgModule decorator there?

Comment: @WillAlexander OK so that did it. I don't have an answer as to why it's there as I generate every component with the angular CLI. I'll have to look into past commits to see if someone else had added that but not likely. Any idea why VSCode seems to ignore that on my machine?

Comment: No idea, I use WebStorm :) but I can't imagine it building correctly, surely the CLI throws an error. If the CLI is throwing that in there, then something has corrupted your schematics and you should simply reinstall the CLI. I suspect, however, that it's an accidental copy/pasta :)

Comment: @WillAlexander Yeah it's very strange. He's still having other issues with the whole setup but everything is running as it should on my end, no errors anywhere. Will keep plugging away at it, thanks!